# Concat a localized string and a dynamic string using DataBinding in Kotlin XML

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a `TextView` in my XML fragment that needs to concat a string from my `strings.xml` file with a dynamic string. Originally, I tried:

`android:text='@{"@string/courses.finalGrade" + ": " + course.grade + "%"}'`

The preview of this works as expected, I see a string of the format: `Final Grade: 90%`.

But when in the simulator, it prints out `@string/courses.finalGrade: 95%`

Is there a way to concat a string from the strings.xml file AND a dynamic string in the xml fragment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this needs to be done programmatically. You can make the string resource be something like `Final Grade: %s%` and then use `String.format()`.

Comment: Have you tried using `"@string/courses.finalGrade"` withouth the quotes? Like this it's just a simple string with content looking like a string resource. The preview might just ignore the quotes and look correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Android data binding supports string formatting. If you define your text resource like:

```
<string name="some_text_id">"Some text about final grade: %1$s"</string>
```

You can then use this text resource with data binding like

```
android:text="@{@string/some_text_id(course.grade)}"
```

It will be the same thing as using String.format(...) programmatically.